# How can I create calendar notifications in Anaplan?

Tags: anaplan-api

I have a TQM model in which I compile data from different department users to calculate the quota.
I want to add a functionality in which I create a calendar and input data such as start and end date to submit the data for different departments, on the basis of the dates I want to display some particular notifications on some dashboards that the users use prompting them to submit the data before date.

Can someone guide me on how to proceed with this use case?

I have not tried anything yet.